# Cakephp 4 - Implement authorization per route

Tags: cakephp

I have specific routes for admin tasks (/admin/...).
The users are in groups (admin, user)

With the authorization plugin, what is the simple way to allow only admin users to /admin routes ?

Is it possible with a policy ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, let me know, if I can improve it :

I have created a policy:

```
class UserPolicy
{
    /**
     * Check if $user have admin access
     *
     * @param Authorization\IdentityInterface $user The user.
     * @param App\Model\Entity\Users $u
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canAdminAccess(IdentityInterface $user, $u)
    {
        return (bool)($user->group_id === GROUP_ADMIN);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in each admin controller, in beforeFilter method, I call authorize:

```
public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Authorization->authorize($this->user,'adminAccess');
}
```